# Text-input with checkboxes and js

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to create a map, with an option wich adds names to the dif. streets. My plan was to include this feature with checkboxes and usemap-information.

Due to my limited understanding on how these components work together, I hit a stand-still, here is my non-functional code:

```
<head>
    <script>
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
    var posting = document.getElementById("post_location");

    function visVei(){
    if (checkbox1.checked){posting="
    <map name='kartet_info' style='cursor:help'>
    <Area shape=poly coords=326, 463, 278, 103, 286, 101, 336, 464 onmouseover=writeText2('Prinsen Gate'); onmouseout=writeText2('');/></map>"
    }
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

This is supposed to get written to:

```
 <span id="post_location" style="display:none;"></span>
```

once

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_1" id="checkbox1" onchange="visVei();"><span class="in_check_1">Gatenavn</span></input>
</form>
```

Is checked off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
var posting = document.getElementById("post_location");

function visVei(){
    if (checkbox1.checked){
        posting.innerHTML="<map name='kartet_info' style='cursor:help'><Area shape=poly coords=326, 463, 278,103, 286, 101, 336, 464 onmouseover=writeText2('Prinsen Gate'); onmouseout=writeText2('');/></map>";
        posting.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: no, that still gives no feedback, btw, the site ain't supposed to reload once a checkbox is selected, if that matters?

Comment: I see you use onchange - event, be sure to press TAB button after clicking the checkbox. I you don't want that bind it to the onclick - event

Comment: O, and move your script block to the end of your page, now the getDocumentById might fail because DOM is not ready yet